# style a tag and input tag the same

Tags: html, css, input, styles

I want to style the `a` and the `input` the same, but there's a kind of padding around the input or something. How do I solve this? Fiddle below.

**I'm using Firefox**

Output:

[image: example]

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="lala" />
<a>lala</a>
```

CSS:

```
input{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-spacing: none;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;

    float: left;
    background-color: #005f83;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
a{
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #005f83;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

This fiddle explains it all I guess:

http://jsfiddle.net/bqhL9fej/

I tried a lot but nothing works.
I want my `<input>` to look the same as the `<a>`, NOT the other way around.
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Excuse me, I'll edit.

Comment: Make them a part of the same CSS class?

Comment: what padding are you seeing? Can you post an image of what you see?

Comment: they look the same exact to me.  you can change the 'a' class, to 'a, input'.  Also, you can also force style with "!important" but that can get risky for future changes. (ie. color: #fff !important;)

Comment: I posted a picture of my result. I'm using Firefox btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They looked the same to me except for the cursor.

For that, add **cursor:pointer** to the 'a' styles

Safe practice to follow here would be:

```
input{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-spacing: none;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}

a, input {
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #005f83;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}
```

Comment: I added a picture of my result. I'm using Firefox

Comment: @sabkaraja ...i just give the answer, don´t need to copy

Comment: I didnt copy, we both ended up giving the same solution. You got the points, so chill :)

Comment: Thanks for ::-moz-focus-inner saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Add this, it will remove inner padding and border in Firefox

```
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Works great! Do you know about this problem in other browsers?

Comment: I recommend to use normalize.css . makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing. - http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Btw, I see it works great on my fiddle, but I'm using this code in my real code and that doesn't work. `input::-moz-focus-inner {  padding: 0 !important;  border: 0 !important;  font-weight: 300 !important;}` I guess this is another problem?

Comment: @Grafit - can you give me the right answer ...much appreciated

Comment: Just put only the code i give you in the top of your css file... the font size must be on another, like input{font-weight:300;}

Comment: It should work, but it doesn't in here. Since your answer is correct and the fastest, I'll mark it as the best, in spite of the saying in my country "People who ask don't get"